# Can't turn on wifi in System Settings on HP Pavilion 1062er

Tags: 16.04, wireless, hp

I have Ubuntu 16.04. I'm trying to make my WiFi work. First - the indicator on the functional button that supposed to switch wifi doesn't change color when I'm pushing it, but it switches bluetooth. I'm using driver that is recommended by **Software and Updates**. When I go to **System Settings > Network > Wireless** I can't turn on the trigger. 
Laptop model: HP Pavilion 1062er. BIOS vendor: Insyde. BIOS version: F.27

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Broadcom 802.11b/g/n WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [103c:1795]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes


 $ sudo lshw -c network
 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.2
       logical name: eno1
       version: 0a
       serial: 28:92:4a:18:87:b6
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 ip=192.168.0.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:61404000-61404fff memory:61400000-61403fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: e0:06:e6:60:92:d7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:61500000-61503fff
$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: 60000000-60ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000040000000-000000004fffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at 61000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at 50000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Memory at 61700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at 61714000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 61719000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at 61710000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: 61600000-616fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000061400000-00000000614fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: 61500000-615fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    Memory at 61718000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    I/O ports at 4088 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4094 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4090 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4060 [size=32]
    Memory at 61717000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at 61715000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 4040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon

07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at 61600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

07:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at 61404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 61400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Broadcom 802.11b/g/n WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 61500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Where is the `rfkill list` output?

Comment: @Pilot6 Can't paste it into code block :(

Comment: It is hard blocked. Check if it is enabled in BIOS, or reset BIOS to defaults.

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't have any settings of WiFi adapter there, but resetting to default values has helped. Maybe you schould write an answer to let me mark it as right?

Comment: The question is unclear without the laptop model. So such an answer makes no sense, since it is specific to some BIOS. If you specify the model, I can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the wireless adapter is blocked by BIOS.

Reset BIOS to defaults and it may start working.

Everything else looks correct.